# Angular with Storybook do not work on IE11

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer-11, storybook, angular-storybook

I have a pretty basic Angular 10 app. I have added Storybook with `npx sb init`. The project requires the app to run on IE11 (13% of the traffic) so I added `.babelrc` in the project root, removed `not` from the IE in `.browserlistrc` and set the `target` in `tsconfig` to `es5`.

App itself works in IE, but when opening storybook I get the `SCRIPT1002: Syntax error` comming from vendors~main bundle, apparently caused by the following: `class DomAdapter { }`.

What could be done about it? I am out of ideas...

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-classes"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig base

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "lib": [
      "ESNext",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "newLine": "lf",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "pretty": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the necessary polyfills for IE?

Comment: Classes are not polyfilled, it's a syntax error. Polyfills add funcitonality within supported syntax.

Comment: I try to refer to the Storybook [docs](https://storybook.js.org/docs/angular/get-started/setup) and found [this](https://imgur.com/a/oF18Num) information. So it looks like you need to transpile some code to make it work in the IE browser. The Storybook docs shows the setup example for React-JS. I suggest you contact the Storybook [support](https://storybook.js.org/support) to get information about how to configure Storybook with Angular to support the IE browser.